# Python libraries to import for CSRF for Google+ Hybrid Sign In

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-plus

I have an App Engine Python app that I want to use Google+ hybrid sign-in with.  I'm going through the steps here:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

But I'm stuck with "Step 2 - Create an anti-request forgery state token"

Per the instructions, I downloaded the Google APIs client library for Python.:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/

I also installed it using this command:

> easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client

Here is what I copy/pasted to my handler:

```
# Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
# Store it in the session for later validation.
state = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                for x in xrange(32))
session['state'] = state
# Set the Client ID, Token State, and Application Name in the HTML while
# serving it.
response = make_response(
    render_template('index.html',
                CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID,
                STATE=state,
                APPLICATION_NAME=APPLICATION_NAME))
```

When I run it on the dev server, I get this:

> NameError: global name 'session' is not defined

Question is, what do I need to import from the client library to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the rest of the code from the sample app? i.e. https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-python/blob/master/signin.py

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll take a look at that code!